# Passive Scan in OWASP ZAP

Tags: owasp, zap

I have started learning OWASP ZAP and I am confused about passive scanning in OWASP ZAP.

On right clicking the node in Site tree I do not see any passive scanning option, however under Tools | Options I am able to see Passive Scan Rules.

1. How Can I run Passive Scan in OWASP ZAP?
2. Is the "URL to attack" in the **Quick Start** same as Active Scan after Spidering

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They run by default, so you have to actually choose to disable them :)
ZAP will run the (enabled) passive scan rules against all URLs that are either proxied through ZAP or visited by either of the spiders.
https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-core-help/wiki/HelpStartConceptsPscan

Cheers,

Simon (ZAP Project Lead)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. And I can see the answer for my second question at https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-core-help/wiki/HelpAddonsQuickstartQuickstart